# How to cleanup XML response in node?

Tags: node.js, xml

I have an XML file pulled from an API that I would like to cleanup and convert to JSON. How can I remove the superflous data such as the envelope and header but keep just the product data please?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>
                2019-10-17T13:53:13.751Z
            </u:Created>
            <u:Expires>
                2019-10-17T13:58:13.751Z
            </u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <GetItemMastersResponse xmlns="http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/2013/08">
        <GetItemMastersResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxxx.xxxx.xxx.Models.Inventory" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ItemMaster>
                <a:Active>
                    false
                </a:Active>
                <a:Alias i:nil="true"/>
                <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.Models.Admin"/>
                <a:BarcodeFormat>
                    7
                </a:BarcodeFormat>
                <a:BarcodeNumber>
                    60000000425
                </a:BarcodeNumber>
                <a:CategoryId>
                    1
                </a:CategoryId>
                <a:Cost>
                    1250.0000
                </a:Cost>
                <a:DefaultPOLevel>
                    false
                </a:DefaultPOLevel>
                <a:DepartmentId>
                    1
                </a:DepartmentId>
                <a:Depth i:nil="true"/>
                <a:Description>
                    725 HUNTER 12G 28" M/C
                </a:Description>
            </a:ItemMaster>
```

Comment: What have you already tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro) for that purpose.
write an xpath-based template to specify what attributes you would like to keep, how do you want to name it in the json output; something like below

[image]

example

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')
const fs = require('fs')

const xml = fs.readFileSync('examples/ean.xml', 'utf-8')
const template = {
    cache_key: '/HotelListResponse/cacheKey',
    hotels: ['//HotelSummary', {
        hotel_id: 'hotelId',
        name: 'name',
        rooms: ['RoomRateDetailsList/RoomRateDetails', {
            rates: ['RateInfos/RateInfo', {
                currency: 'ChargeableRateInfo/@currencyCode',
                non_refundable: 'boolean(nonRefundable = "true")',
                price: 'number(ChargeableRateInfo/@total)'
            }],
            room_name: 'roomDescription',
            room_type_id: 'roomTypeCode'
        }]
    }],
    session_id: '/HotelListResponse/customerSessionId'
}

;(async function () {
    const result = await transform(xml, template)
    console.log(result)
})()
```